# Checking for empty JTextField before user input

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield

```
private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    public CalculateButtonHandler(JTextField initialAmmount, JTextField yearsToMaturity, JTextField interestRate){
        double endingBalance;
        String text = interestRate.getText();
        int interestRateInt = Integer.parseInt(text);

        String text1 = yearsToMaturity.getText();
        int yearsToMaturityInt = Integer.parseInt(text);

        String text2 = initialAmount.getText();
        int initialAmountInt = Integer.parseInt(text);

        endingBalance = initialAmountInt * Math.pow((1 + interestRateInt/1), 1 *           yearsToMaturityInt);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    }
}
```

Current run-time error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

I'm assuming that the run-time error occurs because there is no input when the program runs and the user has no chance to input a string to be parsed to an int.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to check for this.

Comment: well a simple solution could be, assuming if it is happening at button click, disabling the button until all valid inputs are entered.

Comment: Consider using a `JSpinner` with a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) instead of the `JTextField`.

Comment: Btw, there's a typo in your code - you use Integer.parseInt(text) three times, even though the variables are named text, text1 and text2.

Answer (score 0):

The code to handle the on-button-clicked event needs to be in the actionPerformed method, not in the constructor.

```
private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    private final JTextField interestRate;
    private final JTextField yearsToMaturity;
    private final JTextField interestRate;

    public CalculateButtonHandler(JTextField initialAmmount, JTextField     yearsToMaturity, JTextField interestRate) {
        this.initialAmmount = initialAmmount;
        this.yearsToMaturity = yearsToMaturity;
        this.interestRate = interestRate;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       double endingBalance;
       String text = interestRate.getText();
       int interestRateInt = Integer.parseInt(text);

       String text1 = yearsToMaturity.getText();
       int yearsToMaturityInt = Integer.parseInt(text);

       String text2 = initialAmount.getText();
       int initialAmountInt = Integer.parseInt(text);

       endingBalance = initialAmountInt * Math.pow((1 + interestRateInt/1), 1 *           yearsToMaturityInt);
   }
}
```

Comment: After I moved the code inside actionPerformed method, it compiled fine and the initial runtime error was fixed, but now I'm stuck at

"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "CD Interest Rate: "

Comment: That happens when you click on the button, right? Are you clicking on it without having filled-in the parameters into the text fields? As @Shrikant Havale pointed out, if you want to prevent the user from doing that, how about disabling the button until all the values have been filled in? Or maybe use default values? Depends on your actual use case.

Comment: That error occurs ~before~ the interface even appears on the screen.

Comment: Are you sure you're registering this action listener to the button, like button.addActionListener(new CalculateButtonHandler()), and not to some other component? In yes than the error you're getting is most likely not related to this handler you're showing us, as the code in actionPerformed should only be executed when you click the button. Maybe if your application is small, include the whole code.